# Return a data out of a Callback Function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, callback

I am trying to make an chrome-extension. But i have a trouble with returning values out of callback function.
Here is my codes;
***content.js***

```
let filename="block.jpg";
let imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

function iletisim(callback, web_adr){

    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({text: web_adr}, function(response) {

    callback(response);
    }); 
}

function gonder_al(param1){
    console.log("gonder_al ",param1);
    
}

for (imgElt of imgs){
    
    iletisim(gonder_al, imgElt.src);    
    let url = chrome.extension.getURL(filename);
    imgElt.src=url;

};
```

I want to replace images on the web page under some conditions, which are background.js sends. On this code need to use the `callback(response)` under the for loop? It seems not possible with sync callback functions but i am not familiar with with java async functions.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) for a *very* similar problem.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your code, you could simplify it like this: `chrome.runtime.sendMessage({text: web_adr}, callback)`. Please add details on what doesn't work. Also don't forget to declare items as `let` or `const` in loops, in your case `for (const imgElt of imgs)`

Comment: i just need to use the data inside the ```param1``` variable in for loop. but i could not get access the data. thanks for help @GuerricP